# Excel to php remove tabulations and unused chars

Tags: php, excel, phpoffice

I use phpOffice library to read data from an Excel file and convert it to a php array, here his the code providing the php array from excel file data:

```
$spreadsheet= \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('/User/myMac/exampl.xls');

$data = $spreadsheet_fond->getActiveSheet->toArray();
var_dump($data[0][0]); // display the value of first cellule.
```

OUTPUT:

`"/  221,066,768\  ‚¬ "`

What I really want:

`"221,066,768"`

I've tried `trim(preg_match('#[/‚¬\\\\]#', '', $data[0][0]))` and I've got the following results:

`"221,066,768  ‚"` why does the char "‚" was not replaced?

I see that this char `"‚"` is different than `","`  `‚,`.

**UPDATE**

using method `getCollection()` give the real value, but I'm interested in `toArray()`method.

code:

```
$data = $spreadsheet_fond->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection()->get('A1')->getValue();
var_dump($data);
```

OUTPUT:

`221066767.5` // notice that it returns the original value without applying rounding.

Comment: What did you actually put in that cell in Excel?

Comment: here is the content of that cellule:  221 066 768

Comment: Really? Thats a little odd?

Comment: See my comment update

Answer (score 0):

When applying `utf8_decode()` function on `$data[0][0]` the output is:
`221,066,768\  ??`

The following code solve the issue:

```
$result = trim(preg_match('#[/?\\\\]#', '', utf8_decode($data[0][0])));
var_dump($result);
```

OUTPUT:

`221,066,768`